# How to fix 'Error: unable to open database file' in Flask app?

Tags: python, flask, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm creating a Flask server that will display information queried from an sqlite3 database. However, when I try to access the database file after running the localhost, it returns the following error.

```
File "C:\Users\Connor\Documents\Parking\app\routes.py", line 13, in index
    con = sqlite3.connect(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Mar/2019 20:30:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I'm almost positive that the problem stems from `sqlite:///`, but I can't figure it out. None of the solutions suggested seem to have the answer either.

routes.py

```
from app import app
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, request, render_template, 
session, url_for
import sqlite3

app.secret_key = app.config['SECRET_KEY']

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    con = sqlite3.connect(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Lot")
    data = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)
```

config.py

```
import os

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

class Config(object):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite:///" + os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'app.db')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    DEBUG = True
    SECRET_KEY = 'development key'
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Printing `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']` returns `sqlite:///C:\Users\Connor\Documents\Parking\app.db`. I would assume the forward slashes are the root of my problem. I've tried several variants of os.path but to no avail.

Oddly enough, when I manually type in my path, the database displays just fine AND its data can be manipulated in the admin portal. When I use `os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'app.db')`, the database displays, but I can't manipulate its data in the admin portal. When I use `"sqlite:///" + os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'app.db')`, I can't access the database at all.

I believe I'm using `sqlite:///` correctly as per [this document](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html), so maybe I'm just missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using the sqlalchemy connection url, but trying to connect directly through the sqlite3 api.

This line of code from within your `index()` route:

```
con = sqlite3.connect(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])
```

...calls the `sqllite3.connect()` function, and you are passing that your sqlalchemy connection url: `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite:///" + os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'app.db')`.

Here is the function signature of `sqlite3.connect()`:

```
sqlite3.connect(database[, timeout, detect_types, isolation_level, check_same_thread, factory, cached_statements, uri])
```

And here is an excerpt form the documentation about what can be passed as the `database` parameter:

> database is a path-like object giving the pathname (absolute or
>   relative to the current working directory) of the database file to be
>   opened.

`sqllite:///some/path/to/app.db` is not a valid pathname and that's why the error is raised.

You've gone to all the trouble of configuring `flask_sqlalchemy`, so you may as well use it!

```
from app import app, db  # <== notice import of db here
from flask import (Flask, flash, redirect, request, render_template,
                   session, url_for)

app.secret_key = app.config['SECRET_KEY']

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    data = db.session.execute("SELECT * FROM Lot").fetchall()
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)
```

This has the added bonus of keys included session management that comes with Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.